# No matter how many np's do I use, rank 0 always comes last

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, rank, mpich

I have been trying to do tasks and through all of them, when I try to print something (and do anything else) to see the ranks ranking, I see that the rank 0, which should be the first one then rank1, rank2, etc, is always the last of the ranks.

mpich version = mpich-3.3.2 
Windows 10 (ubuntu terminal)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not specified in MPI standard how to order the stdout from all the nodes. i.e The order to print is not defined ([see](https://books.google.de/books?id=GufgfWSHt28C&lpg=PA138&ots=6mYo24qTpk&dq=since%20the%20mpi%20standard%20impose%20no%20requirement%20on&pg=PA138#v=onepage&q=since%20the%20mpi%20standard%20impose%20no%20requirement%20on&f=false)).

Sometimes, when you try printing a large string, you can even observe that the output from different ranks are merged and printed. To summarize, if you need to print in order from `rank 0` to `rank N`, you may have to write extra lines of code. `Rank 0` always printing at last in your example is also not deterministic. It will vary.

Below is an excerpt from the book  *[An Introduction to Parallel Programming by Peter Pacheco](http://www.e-tahtam.com/~turgaybilgin/2013-2014-guz/ParalelProgramlama/ParallelProg.pdf)* about I/O in MPI.

> Although the MPI standard doesn’t specify which processes have access
>   to which I/O devices, virtually all MPI implementations allow all the processes in
>   MPI COMM WORLD full access to stdout and stderr, so most MPI implementations
>   allow all processes to execute printf and fprintf(stderr, ...).
>   However, most MPI implementations don’t provide any automatic scheduling of
>   access to these devices. That is, if multiple processes are attempting to write to, say, stdout, the order in which the processes’ output appears will be unpredictable.
>   Indeed, it can even happen that the output of one process will be interrupted by the
>   output of another process. The reason this happens is that the MPI processes are “competing” for access to
>   the shared output device, stdout, and it’s impossible to predict the order in which the
>   processes’ output will be queued up. Such a competition results in nondeterminism.
>   That is, the actual output will vary from one run to the next. [See Page 98](http://www.e-tahtam.com/~turgaybilgin/2013-2014-guz/ParalelProgramlama/ParallelProg.pdf) for more.